# Google Cloud Storage: Application platform

Tags: google-cloud-storage

We are planning to host our application on  Google Cloud storage, i just wanted to confirm on what kind of application i can host over Google's infrastructure. We have around 40-45 application comprising of .net, SAP, filenet system etc.  Will i be able to host them on Google Cloud Storage.

I have researched for working of deploying application using RESTful API, but how about other platform application.

Thanks,
Vinit

Comment: You realize Cloud Storage is just about storing data? You cannot deploy and run apps on Cloud Storage. Running apps is what App Engine (Python or Java web apps) or Compute Engine (Linux virtual server) are about.

Comment: Thanks for the update and clarification Philipp. So i 'll be able to deploy any application on Google Compute Engine? (as mentioned in previous post)

Comment: If your app runs on Linux it should be able to run on GCE. Check out https://cloud.google.com/products/compute-engine for the details.